# Azure Function developed in .Net6 , not able to inject dependencies from another project from the same solution file. Tried byStartupclass.NOt working

Tags: azure, function, dependencies

Azure Function developed in.Net6 is not able to inject dependencies from another project from the same solution file. I Already Tried adding the Startup class which was inherited from the FunctionsStartup abstract class. But that way it is looking for dependent to dependent dependency and I could not inject for the UnitofFactory class.
Another way was, by changing the newly created AzureFunction project's Output Type from ClassLibrary to ConsoleApplication. I did that but here even though I have added a new program.cs file, it was never hit while executing the project. I am not sure what next can be done.

This is my startup class -

```cs
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Test.AzureFunctions.Startup))]

namespace Test.AzureFunctions
    {
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
       {
      
       public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder2) {
    
           builder2.Services.AddScoped<IMapperUnitOfWorkFactory, MapperUnitOfWorkFactory>();

           builder2.Services.AddScoped<IEntityOpsApiClient, EntityOpsApiClient>();
}
}
```

Code of Test1Function.cs class

```cs
namespace Test.AzureFunctions.Functions
{
    public class TestFunction1
    {
        private readonly IMapperUnitOfWorkFactory _unitOfWorkFactory;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IEntityOpsApiClient _entityOpsApiClient;
      
 

        public TestFunction1(
            IMapperUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory, 
            IEntityOpsApiClient entityOpsApiClient) {
            _unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory.ThrowIfNull(nameof(unitOfWorkFactory));
            _entityOpsApiClient = entityOpsApiClient;
         
            }
        [FunctionName("TestFunction1")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();          
                    using var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkFactory.Create();
                    var client = unitOfWork.ClientRepository.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ClientId == 1).Result;
                   
            }

        }
    }
```

When I have used the startup class to inject dependency my code throws an exception when trying to create a unitOfFactory Object in this line

```cs
using var unitOfWork = - _unitOfWorkFactory.Create();
```

I tried 2 approaches but could not inject dependencies in the Azure Function.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

#My Directory

```
FunctionApp2.sln/
|-- ClassLibrary1/
|   |-- Class1.cs
|-- FunctionApp2/
|   |-- Function1.cs
|   |-- Startup.cs
|   |-- host.json
|   |-- local.settings.json
```

[image]

**`Class1.cs`:**

```cs
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Class1(string name)
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

**`FunctionApp2.csproj`;**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**`Function1.cs`:**

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            var myObject = new Class1("Vivek");

            log.LogInformation($"Created MyClass object with ID: {myObject.Id}, Name: {myObject.Name}");
        }
    }
}
```

**`Startup.cs`:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using ClassLibrary1;


[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp2.Startup))]

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

## `OUTPUT`:

[image]